# Не отображаются идентификаторы из коллекций Entity Framework

Tags: c#, excel, entity-framework, openxml, closedxml

Подскажите хорошую библиотеку для выгрузки отчетов в Excel.

Попробовала https://closedxml.github.io/ClosedXML.Report/docs/ru/ но возникли трудности с тем, чтобы подружить с EF. (Не видит идентификаторы)

```
public static void Report()
{
    const string outputFile = @".\Output\report.xlsx";
    var template = new XLTemplate(@".\Templates\Simple.xlsx");

    using (var db = new DepartReportDBEntities())
    {
        var cust = db.Customers;
        template.AddVariable(cust);
        template.Generate();
    }

    template.SaveAs(outputFile);

    //Show report
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(outputFile) { UseShellExecute = true });
}
```

---

Попробовала вывести хотя бы одну запись в отчет:

```
public static void Report()
{
    const string outputFile = @".\Output\report.xlsx";
    var template = new XLTemplate(@".\Templates\Simple.xlsx");

    using (var db = new DepartReportDBEntities())
    {
        var cust = db.Customers.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
        template.AddVariable(cust);
        template.Generate();
    }

    template.SaveAs(outputFile);

    //Show report
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(outputFile) { UseShellExecute = true });
}
```

Может у кого есть опыт работы с этой библиотекой, подскажите, как ее настроить для приема перечня объектов, с учетом вложенности данных?

Comment: Я понимаю, что так было указано в примере из сайта библиотеки, но я уверен, не стоит мешать получение данных из БД и представление. Отображение данных в файле — представление, работа с Entity Framework — получение данныx. Не согласен, что `DbContext` и классы для работы с Excel должны вообще встречаться в одном методе.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov соглашусь и вы совершенно правы, это тестовый пример из библиотеки. Это только в рамках тестирования для изучения работы.

Answer (score 0):

Я использую `EpPlus`.

Правда, я не знаю, справится ли она с твоим подходом или нет.

Когда я пишу в Excel через нее, то я построчно в цикле обрабатываю каждую строчку своей коллекции и не с какими проблемами не сталкиваюсь, в то время, как ты пуляешь всю коллекцию целиком.

Хотя, метод работы с коллекциями присутствует `LoadFromCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

у себя использовал вариант с [ExcelExportHelper](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/export-to-excel-in-asp-net-mvc/). Правда только плоская таблица выводилась с заголовками